# Introducing S-sequences: which is the shortest to contain all integers 1 to 20?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, optimization, number-theory

Consider a sequence (finite or infinite) of different positive integers, such as the following, in which the first term is 1, and thereafter the *n*th term is either the previous term plus *n*, minus *n*, times *n*, or divided by *n*.

**1**, **3**, **6**, 10, **2**, 12, **5**, 40, 31, 21, 32, 20, 33, 19, **4**, ...

Call such a sequence an *S-sequence* (for N. J. Sloane).

- a) Prove that for all positive integers *N*, there is a *S-sequence* which contains, in some order, all integers up to *N* (the above contains all integers up to 6).
- b) Which is the *S-sequence* of shortest length that contains, in some order, all the integers between 1 and 20?
- c) Which is the *S-sequence* containing all integers between 1 and 20, and whose largest term is as small as possible?

[The "Slightly Spooky Sequence" Game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120269/the-slightly-spooky-sequence-game?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Duplicates are not allowed inside the sequence?

Comment: @DrunkWolf No, duplicates are not allowed. Here is an S-sequence, found by my student Nicolás García, which covers 1 to 10: 1, 3, 9, 13, 8, 14, 2, 16, 7, 17, 6, 18, 5, 19, 4, 64, 47, 29, 10.

Comment: Nice to see you return the favor to Neil :)

Comment: Could you share a proof of part a)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer to part c):

> This sequence has maximum term 100 (and length 50):
>  1 2 5 20 100 94 87 95 86 96 85 73 60 74 59 75 58 76 4 24 3 66 43 19 44 18 45 17 46 16 47 15 48 14 49 13 50 12 51 11 52 10 53 9 54 8 55 7 56 6

Found with the following Python code:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

best_n = 0

candidates = [(1, [1], set((1,)))]
while candidates:
    prev_max, prev_list, prev_set = heappop(candidates)
    n = len(prev_list) + 1

    max_n = min(set(range(1, (n+1)+1)) - prev_set) - 1
    if max_n > best_n:
        best_n = max_n
        print(max_n, ':', prev_list)

    prev_num = prev_list[-1]
    new_nums = [prev_num + n, prev_num * n]
    if prev_num > n:
        new_nums.append(prev_num - n)
    q, m = divmod(prev_num, n)
    if m == 0:
        new_nums.append(q)
    for new_num in new_nums:
        if new_num not in prev_set:
            new_list = prev_list.copy()
            new_set = prev_set.copy()
            new_list.append(new_num)
            new_set.add(new_num)
            new_max = max(prev_max, new_num)

            heappush(candidates, (new_max, new_list, new_set))
```

Here are the sequences with the smallest maximum term for *N* up to 24:

> ```
> 1 (1): 1
> 2 (2): 1 2
> 3 (6): 1 3 6 2
> 4 (10): 1 3 6 2 10 4
> 5 (10): 1 2 5 9 4 10 3
> 6 (12): 1 2 6 10 5 11 4 12 3
> 9 (19): 1 3 9 13 8 14 2 16 7 17 6 18 5 19 4
> 12 (48): 1 2 5 20 25 19 26 18 27 37 48 4 17 3 45 29 12 30 11 31 10 32 9 33 8 34 7 35 6
> 13 (69): 1 2 6 10 5 11 4 12 3 13 24 36 23 37 52 68 51 69 50 30 9 31 8 32 7
> 17 (77): 1 2 6 24 29 23 16 8 17 7 77 65 5 19 4 20 3 54 35 15 36 14 37 13 38 12 39 11 40 10 41 9
> 18 (100): 1 2 5 20 100 94 87 79 70 80 69 81 68 54 39 55 72 4 23 3 63 41 18 42 17 43 16 44 15 45 14 46 13 47 12 48 11 49 10 50 9 51 8 52 7 53 6
> 20 (100): 1 2 5 20 100 94 87 95 86 96 85 73 60 74 59 75 58 76 4 24 3 66 43 19 44 18 45 17 46 16 47 15 48 14 49 13 50 12 51 11 52 10 53 9 54 8 55 7 56 6
> 24 (109): 1 2 5 20 4 24 31 39 30 3 33 21 8 22 7 23 6 108 89 109 88 66 43 19 44 18 45 17 46 16 47 15 48 14 49 13 50 12 51 11 52 10 53 9
> ```

Some values of *N* are missing because their S-sequences have the same length and maximum term as the S-sequence for a larger *N*.

Answer (score 7):

b) The shortest sequence is

> Length 37:
>  $1,2,5,20,15,9,16,8,17,7,18,6,19,33,48,3,51,918,937,917,896,874,38,14,39,13,40,12,41,11,42,10,43,77,112,148,4$

Method:

> By computer. Sort the heap with the following heuristic:
>  `sequence.Length + MinNeeded(sequence)`
>  `MinNeeded()` (pseudocode below) returns an extremely rough approximate of the minimum number of remaining elements which would be needed to produce a valid sequence. The method may return a number too low, but never too high, which makes it safe to use.
>
> ```
> int MinNeeded(sequence)
> {
>   min = 0;
>
>   // The amount of numbers in the range [1, 20] which are not in the sequence yet
>   remaining = 20 - Matches(sequence, 1, 20);
>
>   // best case: as long as n is less than 20, we could only use elements in [2, 20]
>   min += Max(0, 20 - sequence.Length);
>   remaining -= min;
>
>   // Once n >= 20, the remaining part of the sequence
>   // can never have two consecutive elements which
>   // are both within the range [2, 20].
>   // The best case scenario is two elements per value in range [2, 20]
>   min += remaining * 2;
>
>   // to deal with extremely large numbers
>   // we add the minimum amount of operations
>   // it would take to get the current number
>   // back to [2, 20]. A check if it is 
>   // actually divisible is not needed here,
>   // it's good enough.
>   n = sequence.Last();
>   c = 0;
>   for (i = sequence.Length + 1; n > 20; i++)
>   {
>     n /= i;
>     c++;
>   }
>
>   min += Max(0, c - 1);
>
>   return min - 1;
> }
> ```

Here are the shortest ones for all $N$ up to $30$. My method is currently too naive to reasonably calculate anything bigger.

> ```
> 1 (1): 1
> 2 (2): 1,2
> 3 (4): 1,3,6,2
> 4 (6): 1,3,6,2,10,4
> 5 (7): 1,2,5,20,4,10,3
> 6 (9): 1,2,6,10,5,11,4,12,3
> 7 (12): 1,2,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,30,19,7
> 8 (15): 1,3,9,13,8,14,2,16,7,17,6,18,5,19,4
> 9 (15): 1,3,9,13,8,14,2,16,7,17,6,18,5,19,4
> 10 (17): 1,2,6,10,15,9,16,8,17,7,77,65,5,19,4,20,3
> 11 (20): 1,2,5,9,4,10,3,11,99,89,78,66,53,39,24,8,25,7,26,6
> 12 (21): 1,2,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,13,24,36,23,9,135,151,134,152,8,28,7
> 13 (21): 1,2,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,13,24,36,23,9,135,151,134,152,8,28,7
> 14 (26): 1,2,5,9,4,10,3,24,15,25,14,26,13,27,12,28,11,198,217,197,176,8,31,7,32,6
> 15 (26): 1,2,5,9,4,10,3,24,15,25,14,26,13,27,12,28,11,198,217,197,176,8,31,7,32,6
> 16 (29): 1,2,6,24,120,20,13,5,14,4,15,3,16,224,209,193,210,228,12,32,11,33,10,34,9,35,8,36,7
> 17 (31): 1,2,5,9,14,8,15,7,16,6,17,29,42,56,71,55,72,4,23,3,63,85,62,38,13,39,12,40,11,41,10
> 18 (32): 1,2,5,9,14,8,15,7,16,6,17,29,42,3,18,288,4896,272,253,273,13,35,12,36,11,37,10,38,67,97,128,4
> 19 (34): 1,2,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,30,19,31,18,32,17,33,16,34,15,35,14,36,13,312,7800,300,327,299,270,9,40,8,41,7
> 20 (37): 1,2,5,20,15,9,16,8,17,7,18,6,19,33,48,3,51,918,937,917,896,874,38,14,39,13,40,12,41,11,42,10,43,77,112,148,4
> 21 (41): 1,2,6,10,15,9,16,8,17,7,77,65,5,19,4,20,3,21,40,60,1260,1238,1215,1191,1216,1242,46,18,522,552,521,489,456,490,14,50,13,51,12,52,11
> 22 (42): 1,2,6,24,19,25,18,26,234,244,255,267,280,20,5,21,4,22,3,60,39,17,40,16,41,15,42,14,43,13,44,12,45,11,46,10,47,9,48,8,49,7
> 23 (44): 1,2,5,20,4,24,31,39,30,3,33,21,8,22,7,23,6,108,89,109,88,66,43,19,44,18,45,17,46,16,47,15,48,14,49,13,50,12,51,11,52,10,53,9
> 24 (44): 1,2,5,20,4,24,31,39,30,3,33,21,8,22,7,23,6,108,89,109,88,66,43,19,44,18,45,17,46,16,47,15,48,14,49,13,50,12,51,11,52,10,53,9
> 25 (45): 1,3,6,2,7,13,20,12,21,11,22,10,23,9,24,8,25,43,62,42,882,904,881,857,832,32,5,33,4,120,89,121,88,54,19,55,18,56,17,57,16,58,15,59,14
> 26 (46): 1,2,5,20,15,21,14,22,13,23,12,24,11,25,10,26,9,27,8,28,7,29,6,144,119,93,66,94,65,35,4,36,3,102,137,173,136,98,59,19,60,18,61,17,62,16
> 27 (46): 1,2,5,20,15,21,14,22,13,23,12,24,11,25,10,26,9,27,8,28,7,29,6,144,119,93,66,94,65,35,4,36,3,102,137,173,136,98,59,19,60,18,61,17,62,16
> 28 (46): 1,2,5,20,15,21,14,22,13,23,12,24,11,25,10,26,9,27,8,28,7,29,6,144,119,93,66,94,65,35,4,36,3,102,137,173,136,98,59,19,60,18,61,17,62,16
> 29 (46): 1,2,5,20,15,21,14,22,13,23,12,24,11,25,10,26,9,27,8,28,7,29,6,144,119,93,66,94,65,35,4,36,3,102,137,173,136,98,59,19,60,18,61,17,62,16
> 30 (52): 1,2,5,9,4,24,17,25,16,26,15,27,14,28,13,29,12,30,11,31,10,220,243,267,242,216,8,36,7,37,6,38,71,105,3,108,145,107,146,106,65,23,66,22,67,21,68,20,69,19,70,18
> ```